Having problem when Saving or executing Workflow in maximo PR application
The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is out of range for its corresponding use.. SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, DRIVER=4.26.14
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlDataException: The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is out of range for its corresponding use.. SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, DRIVER=4.26.14
Tried to change the description of PR and item code description, New PR without item lines.

This is not for stackoverflow.  Refer to your vendor for support of Maximo PR.
